# Flash Builder how do I get data from the fields of the first row of datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, flex4, builder, flash-builder

Flash Builder:

How do I get data from the fields of the first row of datagrid spark?
I want to print them on the screen.

I'm starting in Flash Builder and searched a lot for this information and could not find.
I will be very grateful for this information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally supply the data to the data grid via it's [dataProvider](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#dataProvider) property which is typed as the interface, [IList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/IList.html). The `IList` interface defines a method named [getItemAt()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/IList.html#getItemAt%28%29) that you can use to retrieve an item from a specified array index.

The most common `IList` implementations are `ArrayCollection`, `ArrayList`, and `XMLListCollection`. Assuming you have created one of these collections and, you can then do something like this:

```
// note the type of 'item' can be whatever class you're storing in the array
// it doesn't have to be 'Object'
var item:Object = myCollection.getItemAt(0);
```

If you need more help than this, you need to show the code that you're using.